# Photoshop 3D and Vanishing Point filter: can they work together?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d-modeling

I've stumbled upon Vanishing Point filter completely accidentally. It's a great tool and I logically assumed that it should work with 3D extension of Photoshop, like for example help to align 3D models properly along the perspective planes, set proper lighting and exact camera angle, etc. But now I can't find connection between two. Is there any?

Can I for example export perspective planes that I define in Vanishing Point filter into the 3D layer and make 3D objects in it to interact with them (snap to grid or something)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no integration between the two per se but you can export the grid to Photoshop as a new layer and then use it as a 'tool' for helping you align everything while manipulating 3D objects.

You can export it like this:

1. Create a new blank layer
2. Open Vanishing Point
3. Create all the grids (NB Go for blue grids)
4. Click the drop down menu on the top left in Vanishing Point and choose 'Render grids to Photoshop'
5. You should have a grid with transparency on your layer
6. You can change the color of the grid if you just lock the transparency of a layer and fill it with a desired color.

Alternatively you can choose 'Return 3D layer to Photoshop' and you will get a white 3D model of the grid which you can then use in 3D like any other 3D object.

[Unfortunately, I don't know whether you can get a 3D model of a blue grid, but you can always change the faces of the new white model to appear like a grid.]